# Flutter The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am returning a data from an API using flutter and I have a problem telling me that

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the
return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

This is my method:

```
Future<void> getDoctorsFromApi() async {
    List<int> ids = await findAllDoctor().then((list) {
      return list.map((e) => e.syncedId).toList();
    });
    doctors = await DoctorApi.getDoctors(ids).then((response) { // this is the line where error occurs
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        return list.map((model) => Doctor.fromJson(model)).toList();
      } else {
        _showMyDialog();
      }
    });
    setState(() {
      insertDoctors(database!);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please do not combine `.then()` and `async/await`. It is technically possible, but as you can see right here, it's difficult for the human in front of the screen to understand. So do yourself a favor and make it easy for you (and others) to read and understand your code by using *either* one *or* the other.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to not to use `.then` with `async/await` ?

Comment: Indeed, the whole *point* of having async/await is to *get rid* of those `.then()` chains.

Answer (score 3):

What will be the value of `doctors` if `response.statusCode` is not 200? Handle that
by creating a nullable local variable:

```
final List<Doctor>? result = await DoctorApi.getDoctors(ids).then((response) {
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
    return list.map((model) => Doctor.fromJson(model)).toList();
  }
  return null;
});

if (result == null) {
  _showMyDialog();

} else {
  doctors = result;
  setState(() => insertDoctors(database!));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add some return or throw statement at the end of your function.

```
        setState(() {
      insertDoctors(database!);
    });
    throw ''; # or return something
  }
```